How to enforce a TypeScript type where only one field is a string and all others are numbers?
I'm working with TypeScript and need to define a type for an object where all fields are constrained to be numbers, except for one specific field named order, which should be a string. How can I correctly define this type?
type ExcludeOrder<T> = {
    [K in keyof T as K extends 'order' ? never : K]: number;
};

type SpecificRecord = ExcludeOrder<{ [key: string]: number }> & {
    order: string;
};

const record: SpecificRecord = {
    order: 'first',  
    amount: 100,  
};

errorinfo:
Type '{ order: string; amount: number; price: number; quantity: number; }' is not assignable to type 'SpecificRecord'.
  Type '{ order: string; amount: number; price: number; quantity: number; }' is not assignable to type 'ExcludeOrder<{ [key: string]: number; }>'.
    Property 'order' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)

Is there any way to solve this type issue?

No.
The issue boils down to this:
type MyType = {
  [Key in string]: Key extends 'order' ? string : number;
};

const record: MyType = {
    order: 'first',  //error here
    amount: 100,  
};

type MyType2 = {
    [key in string] : number;
    order : string; //error here
};

None of the above is supported.
This is not supported.
From the docs:

While string index signatures are a powerful way to describe the “dictionary” pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type.

Here is the GH issue.
The rationale the TypeScript team has is that dynamic property access will cause confusion here as to which type to pick.
